# Boot extremely slow, Ubuntu 16.04 blocked

Tags: boot, virtualbox

Dears,

Ubuntu crashed when I install the Guest Additions for VirtualBox, thus I reboot it violently - had no other choice, evertyhing was blocked.

When restarting however this became unusable, boot was pretty normal but once the desktop appeared I cannot do anything so the desktop is slow. In a terminal, entering characters is just impossible as they are either repeated several times or just ignored...
After a while however, it got unblocked and I could get the dmsesg. Below is the link to it. We see something blocking from line 521, related to some floppy (still exist ??) (this even appears several times in the log). 
http://pastebin.com/cEejAhZm

Any idea what is block that strongly for such a long time ??

Thank you for any hint on how to repair this...

Answer (score 0):

Cannot explain, after I rebooted, it recovered :/ And I could finish installing the GA for VirtualBox...
Just would be curious on recovery methods when Linux or Ubuntu desktop do not start properly.
Thanks for reading.

PS: If a moderator want s suppress this thread, please feel free...